# LLC and tax filing with spouse

Tags: taxes, limited-liability-company

In florida my husband and I are the only managing members on an LLC. Are we able to file our taxes with one of us claiming 100% of profits and losses and the other as 0% if we are filing jointly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the operating agreement. If the operating agreement says that the profits and losses are shared equally - then that is what you need to write down in your taxes.

It does matter, since it affects your FICA rights and liabilities (which, I assume, is the reason why you're asking this).

No, you cannot just make up numbers. You need to follow the OA.

Answer (score -1):

When you file a joint return there are no separate numbers for husband and wife. Everything is aggregated together.

Comment: Does that mean that both people are seen as equal partners? I read somewhere that you file each persons tax paid by their percentage of ownership and split that on each schedule C, so I was wanting to know if one spouse can file 100% on their schedule C and the other can file 0%.

Comment: Wrong completely and entirely.